# how to fix the size of a popup window to auto?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, c#-3.0

Currently I'm doing a project in which i needs to collect data from a user and need to generate a PDF based on the user entered data. Before generating the PDF, there should be an option to display the preview of the same PDF.
so i used the below codes:

```
$("#btnPreview").click(function () {

var data = UserData();
model = data.modelnew;
FamilyArray = data.familynew;
$.ajax({
    url: "/CareApplication/Create",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ model: model, Family: FamilyArray, flag: "1" }),
    success: function (data) {
        var myPos = { my: "center top", at: "center top+100", of: window };
        var $dialog = $('<div style="overflow-y: hidden" ></div>')
 .html('<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder"=0" src="' + data + '" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>')
 .dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     height: 650,
     width: 1200,
     title: "Preview",
     position: myPos,
 });
        $dialog.dialog('open');


    }
});

window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

here i have fixed the size of the popup `window(height:650, width:1200)`, due to this the size of the popup window varies for different browsers. So I cant close the popup window.
my question is that Can i fix the size of the pop up window to automatic?
This popup window should display on the same page.

Comment: try by giving height and width in %..

Answer (score 0):

.dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     height: 80%,
     width: 80%,
     title: "Preview",
     position: myPos,
 });

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do the same 
 Either give the value in percentages or you can use $(window) height and width properties to populate the values once on document ready and then can use across the page. Something like

var windowHeight = $(window).height()*0.6;
var windowWidth = $(window).width()*0.6;

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)

Vatsal

Comment: both methods are not working.. i think there will  be an alternate way to do this..

Answer (score 0):

No way to fix the window auto size,But it will differ from browser to browser.
We can't fix the size of the popup window according to my understand.

Comment: Can we set any border properties for this popup window?